# my function wont return the object to be saved in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I cant get the code to return the object and save within the array, the first function is to save the song within the array and the second function it to search for songs already saved in the array

```
function save() {
    //loop to keep adding songs within the array

    var addSong = //create the object inside the function
    {
        title: document.number.title.value,
        artist: document.number.artist.value,
        col: document.number.col.value,
        dur: document.number.dur.value
    };

    //output the song title of the saved song 
    document.number.saved.value = addSong.title;
    return addSong;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------
var sTitle = document.searchSong.searchTitle.value; // assigning the search box to 'sTitle'     
var library = new Array() //array to store each song 
var song = addSong.title;

//-----------------------------------------------------------
//function to search for a song saved in the music() array
function search() {
    //if statement to compare the inputs and see if the song is in      the      
    library
    if (sTitle == song) {
        //if the song title is there then it is output
        document.searchSong.result.value = song;
    } else {
        //if not then 'no song' is output instead
        document.searchSong.result.value = "no song";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are all these properties added to the `document` ?

Comment: because im using forms to get users input to save within the array

Comment: Is this the whole script? Because if that is, you need to call the function "save()" and assign its results to addSong before trying to access its "title" property.

Comment: i've looked up on w3school and other sites and none of their code assigns the results. all of them are like the first section, thats why i dont see why it wont work

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function save() and assign its results of to a variable named addSong.

```
var addSong = save();
var song = addSong.title;
```

Comment: thankyou, how can i make the search function work? i type in the box and nothing appears and web console isnt coming up with an error

Comment: i need to store the data within the array instead of a variable